# Geting XML form website

Tags: php, xml

I try to get data from other website like this :
https://www.wowhead.com/item=65891&xml
I also have this php code:

```
$xml=file_get_contents('http://www.wowhead.com/item=65891&xml');
    $xml=  simplexml_load_string($xml);
    var_dump($xml->item->name);
```

but it's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name text contents, use `__toString()` method:

```
var_dump($xml->item->name->__toString());
//output: string 'Vial of the Sands' (length=17)
```

Comment: its return empty name

Answer (score 2):

This will give you an object of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php):

`$xml->item->name`

You can use its [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method to get the string content:

```
var_dump($xml->item->name->__toString());
```